# Remove node from linked list received as parameter C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class LinkedList and i want to write a method that deletes the node received as a parameter in the method as a pointer.

The method structure should look like this:

```
void LinkedList: : removeAt(ListElem *arg);
```

how do i write this method? cause i cant figure it out

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What are `ListElem`, and `LinkedList` (how are they defined)?

Comment: ***cause i cant figure it out*** Please add your broken attempt + minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

```
void LinkedList: : removeAt(LinkedList *ll, ListElem *arg) {
  if (!ll->head) return; // ll is your linked list object
  if (ll->head == arg) {
    struct ListElem *head = ll->head;
    ll->head = head->next;
    delete head;
    return;
  }
  struct ListElem *current = ll->head;
  while (current->next) {
    if (current->next == arg) {
      struct ListElem *next = current->next;
      current->next = next->next;
      delete next;
      break;
    }
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

Updated according to the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use global variables.